# If $A$ is a noetherian ring, prove that a closed set $X \subset \mathrm{Spec}\,A$ is irreducible if and only if $I(X)=\bigcap_{P \in X} P$ is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> If $A$ is a noetherian ring, prove that a closed set $X \subset \operatorname{Spec} A$ is irreducible if and only if $I(X)=\bigcap_{P \in X} P$ is prime.

This is the problem I am trying to solve. I tried to prove the contrapositive but I couldn't find $I(X_{1})$ and $I(X_{2})$ to find a contradiction.

Comment: do you know the classical proof that prime ideals and irreducible algebraic varieties are in one to one correspondence? I believe you can make the same argument

Comment: Title should be only informative. For the question there is the question box.